# Different integer size usages

Tags: c#, memory, integer

Is there a difference between space (memory) usage of integer `1` and `234234`? How much space would `int.MaxValue` use and just integer `1` use?

I'm incrementing a value in the program everytime the object gets accessed so I can keep the objects with the most usage in memory and others flushed to the disk. Therefore I was thinking the counter (integer) might increase a lot and a lot of memory would be used just for the counter?

Comment: An int is 4 bytes, regardless of the value. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: An integer is an integer, regardless of what it's storing. An integer is typically a 4 byte (32-bit) value, and whether it contains the value `1` or the value `int.MaxValue` it still uses 4 bytes.

Comment: @iefpw 8-bits-per-byte, times 4 = 32-bits. Hence the name "32-bit Integer". The answer is "Yes, same space."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `int.MaxValue` is the largest value which can be represent by a 32 bit integer. If you want a larger value you use `long` which consumes 64 bits. Basically, the amount of memory an integer consumes has nothing to do with it's value.

```
int small = 1 // translates to 0x00000001
```

while

```
int big = int.MaxValue //translates to 0x7FFFFFFF
```

They still consume that same 4 bytes of memory, they just have different values for the bits. The values in my code snippet are represented in hexadecimal, if you don't know how that translates into actual bits just check it out wikipedia.

Comment: @KenWhite was that before my edit? I might just be confused but I think I answered the question correctly and thoroughly. Perhaps I should have just put it as a comment though I don't know of any reason this question wouldn't meet the SO guidelines.

Comment: int.MaxValue translates to 0x7FFFFFFF* (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx)

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: Yes, it was. :-) I posted the comment right after your initial answer, and you edited it a minute or so later.